# Setting database parameters in Zend 3

Tags: mysql, zend-framework3

I'm a serious newbie as it comes to Zend and I'm now forced to work with Zend 3 (and learn it). Fellow developers have done parts of the application and now I'm cloning it on my side.

I receive "Database not selected" in the error log - I have set database.local.php and I think they've set everything else. Credentials are correct.

I'm working on Windows.

Is there anything else I could be missing as it comes to settings or database connection?

Thanks. I will provide any additional info if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As we're dealing with both Zend Framework **AND** a configuration issue, for your next question, please make sure to also include file paths and such.

I'm proceeding with this answer under the assumption that you've created your file here: `/config/database.local.php`.

---

*Note*: using ZF3 myself, I, of course, tried to find your error message "Database not selected", however it comes back with no results. Make sure you copy and paste error messages so users of any framework, cms or another system can more easily help you out.

---

You'll find the problem you're facing in the `application.config.php` file (in the `/config` folder. In here you'll find the following config:

```
// Retrieve list of modules used in this application.
'modules' => require __DIR__ . '/modules.config.php',

// These are various options for the listeners attached to the ModuleManager
'module_listener_options' => [
    // ... other config

    // An array of paths from which to glob configuration files after
    // modules are loaded. These effectively override configuration
    // provided by modules themselves. Paths may use GLOB_BRACE notation.
    'config_glob_paths' => [
        realpath(__DIR__) . '/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local,{,*.}deploy,{,*.}development}.php',
    ],
    // ... other config
],
```

Any of the `*.local.php` or `*.global.php` config files *should* be placed in `/config/autoload/`. Though, if you modify the above config, you could technically place it wherever you'd like.

---

Next, make sure you have the `Zend\Db` module enabled in your configuration. Open up the `/config/modules.config.php` file and make sure `Zend\Db` is in the list of Zend modules to be loaded in.

---

Lastly, you have not provided the config you used, so I'm assuming you made a mistake there. Use something like the config below in your `/config/autoload/database.local.php` file. Technically you could split this over 2 files; a global and a local file. Local files are (/should) not be committed into version control history and as such can contain usernames and passwords. Any other config, such as using `Pdo` for a `driver` could go into global config.

```
'db' => [
    'driver' => 'Pdo',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=zf3;hostname=localhost',
    'username' => 'root', 
    'password' => 'root', 
    'driver_options' => [
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ],
],
```